# Could someone explain how to use Recipient in Spring Integration

Tags: email, spring-integration

I'm trying to use Spring Integration for sending email. I've looked at a couple books and extensively online but I haven't uncovered how to create or use Recipient. This tutorial for sending http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2010/08/09/sending-outbound-smtp-messages-through-gmail-with-spring-integration/  while good in other respects has a gap :

```
   public class MySomeClass {
    @Autowired
       MailGateway mailGateway;

      public void doSomethingMethod() {
      mailGateway.sendMail(recipient);
     }
```

i.e. no explanation how to create, populate or otherwise deal with the static Recipient class.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In terms of Email `recipient` is type of user who will receive a message: `to`, `cc`, `bcc`. See `RecipientType` class. Can you provide more info what do you mean? Maybe it will be just enough for you to use `<int-mail:header-enricher>` ?

Comment: I understand Recipient references a channel as part of a Recipient List Router. So I understand how it might be configured in an application context. If programmatically I so a sendMail() as above how would I populate the Recipient object especially considering according to docs its a static class?

Comment: So my use case would be more dynamic. I would pull an email address from a datastore and send the email rather than always be sending to the same end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing apples and oranges; the `Recipient` class in Gordon's blog has nothing to do with the recipient list router (which routes to one or more `MessageChannel`s).

The `Recipient` here is a simple POJO/JavaBean with information about the Email recipient...

```
recipient.getRecipientEmail();
```

etc.

As Artem says, simply populate the message with appropriate data using a mail header enricher.

See the [documentation for more details](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html#mail-namespace).

Comment: Ok thanks. Rather orange painted apples. Confusing to use a framework class name on a POJO without explanation.

Comment: It's not our blog post :)